# Chrome Extension Javascript var issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, var

I'm new in js code ( come from php/ html/css) and i am trying to create a personal extension for Chrome that allow browser to replace some words with others!

So i have my manifest.json :

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Name1",
  "version": "14.3",
  "description": "Desc1",
   "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "myicon.png",
      "popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
         {
            "matches": [
                "http://*/*",
                "https://*/*"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ],
            "run_at": "document_end"
        }  ]
}
```

And then my content.js

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('*');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    var element = elements[i];

    for (var j = 0; j < element.childNodes.length; j++) {
        var node = element.childNodes[j];

        if (node.nodeType === 3) {
            var text = node.nodeValue;
            var replacedText = text.replace(/[wordtoreplace]/gi, '[neword1]');
            var replacedText = text.replace(/[wordtoreplace2]/gi, '[neword1]');
            var replacedText = text.replace(/[wordtoreplace3]/gi, '[neword1]');
            if (replacedText !== text) {
                element.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(replacedText), node);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But the browser only replace my word1 and not my word2 and 3 :( 
The force can't help, someone can?

Comment: Think how you would do this in a language you know. It would be nothing like this, right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mistake is the re-declaring and initialization of the same variable.
If you declare a variable and you initialize it to a value and immediately after you re-declare the same variable and you initialize with another value the result will be:

```
var myVar = "This is the first var";
var myVar = "Second var";
alert(myVar);
```

**Now the result of alert is "Second var".**

Re-declaring a variable is usefull in some advanced context but completely unuseful for normal programming. A variable, once declared, could not be re-declared because unuseful and the resulting program becomes unreadable.
In any case if you initialize the value for every variable declaration the last one will contain the actual value.

Therefore, your following three lines:

```
var replacedText = text.replace(/[wordtoreplace]/gi, '[neword1]');
var replacedText = text.replace(/[wordtoreplace2]/gi, '[neword1]');
var replacedText = text.replace(/[wordtoreplace3]/gi, '[neword1]');
```

must change to:

```
var replacedText = text.replace(/[wordtoreplace]/gi, '[neword1]');
replacedText = replacedText.replace(/[wordtoreplace2]/gi, '[neword1]');
replacedText = replacedText.replace(/[wordtoreplace3]/gi, '[neword1]');
```

Instead to re-declare the same variable consider to chain the method like in the following example:

```
var text = "word1 word2 word3";
var replacedText =text.replace("word1", "1")
        .replace("word2", "2")
        .replace("word3", "3");
alert(replacedText);
```

Now the content of replacedText is "1 2 3" because applying the replace method to the string means to obtain a new string on wich a can immediately apply again the replace method again and so on.

[REPLACE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace): the flag gi in the replace stands for :

- g: global match
- i: ignore case

Comment: Maybe you know a way to make the js work also in uppercase or lowercase condition? For example "wordtoreplace" = "Wordtoreplace" = "woRDtoreplace" ecc? Thank u again

Comment: @Lorenzo The `i` modifier makes it case-independent.

Comment: Thanks for the help dude! Now it works , but i have this problem that look hard: for example the word i want to replace is "stone" , so the sentence = "stone is on the table" become "neword is on the table". But also the sentence " i love firestone song" become " i love fireneword song". Any way to say only if the word is exactly "stone" => replace  ?

Comment: @Lorenzo You're kind of getting out of bounds of this question - it's better to ask a new one (or even better, search) about regex that matches only complete words.

Comment: @gaemaf Could you add an explanation of _why_ that code is an error? It would be much more helpful.

Comment: @xan is it all ok now?